# Application not responding

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ksoap2

I am sending details to be stored in a database using a web service using KSOAP.This code was working perfectly before and I didn't make any change to it. Now its not working. Please help. I checked the web service and it works. I have attached the log cat details. Please help !!!

```
public class Registration extends Activity{
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/register";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "register";
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:54714/WebSite1/Service.asmx";
Button sqlRegister, sqlView;

EditText  sqlFirstName,sqlLastName,sqlEmail,sqlMobileNumber,sqlCurrentLocation,sqlUsername,sqlPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.registration);
sqlFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
sqlLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLname);
sqlEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
sqlMobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
sqlCurrentLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrentLoc);

sqlUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
sqlPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPwd);

sqlRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

sqlRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bRegister:

                String firstname = sqlFirstName.getText().toString();
                String lastname = sqlLastName.getText().toString();
                String emailadd = sqlEmail.getText().toString();
                String number = sqlMobileNumber.getText().toString();
                String loc = sqlCurrentLocation.getText().toString();
                String uname = sqlUsername.getText().toString();
                String pwd = sqlPassword.getText().toString();

                SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
                Request.addProperty("fname", String.valueOf(firstname));
                Request.addProperty("lname", String.valueOf(lastname));
                Request.addProperty("email", String.valueOf(emailadd));
                Request.addProperty("num", String.valueOf(number));
                Request.addProperty("loc", String.valueOf(loc));
                Request.addProperty("username", String.valueOf(uname));
                Request.addProperty("password", String.valueOf(pwd));
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
                HttpTransportSE httpTransport  = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
                try
                {
                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                    int result =  Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
                    if(result == '1'){
                        Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

            break;
        }
           }
        });
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple reason why you're getting an Application Not Responding error: you are making the web request on the main (UI) thread. There are two rules to the Android threading model: 1) don't block the main thread for more than a couple seconds 2) don't update the UI from off of the main thread. You are violating the first of those rules. You should look into using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do your longer operations.

Comment: To add to what LuxuryMode said: While technically you'll get an ANR after 5 seconds you should really strive to never block the UI thread for anywhere near even 1 second. The users will notice and will think your app is slow =)

Comment: So can i put everything that is inside the button onclick into the doInbackground method of Async Task and just call the Async Task in the button onclick?

Comment: Yes, set up an inner class that extends AsyncTask, then execute it on the onClick. in onPostExecute of your AsyncTask, do whatever you need to with the retrieved data.

Answer (score 1):

`httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`
You are making a network call on the UI thread. You need to do all long running tasks, such as accessing a resource over the network on a separate thread. The API provides a convenience class call `[AsyncTask][1]` that lets you accomplish this easily.

In its simplest form, you would create a class that extends AsyncTask, and then move your `httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` to its `doInBackground` method.